# Commit File to Rollback - Heroku

Tags: git, heroku

I am needing to commit a file to a rolled back commit on Heroku. I am currently running a rollback after a bug caused issues on Master which we are fixing. However I need to update the app.js on the rolled back version. Is this possible?

Comment: What do you mean by "update the `app.js` on the rolled back version"? Do you want to run a previous release, but with some changes?

Comment: Thats exactly it @Chris

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to run a previous release but you need to make changes to it, you're not doing a rollback. A rollback runs the compiled application slug from the previous release; there is no way to change the code in that release.

You need to run from another branch. If your commit graph looks something like this:

```
o---o---o  [old-release]
         \
          o---o  [main]
```

and you want to go back to `old-release` but change something, you'll need to create a new branch off of `old-release`, make your changes there, commit them, and then deploy from that new branch.

One way to do this would be to

1. Create the new branch with `git checkout -b bug-fix old-release`
2. Make your changes
3. Commit
4. Deploy the `bug-fix` branch to Heroku by running `git push bug-fix:main` (or `git push bug-fix:master` if you are using `master` as your main branch)

This will build a whole new release.

Your commit graph will now look something like this:

```
          A  [bug-fix]
         /
o---o---o  [old-release]
         \
          o---o  [main]
```

You might choose to rebase your main development line onto the `bug-fix` branch:

```
            o---o  [main]
           /
          A  [bug-fix]
         /
o---o---o  [old-release]
```

Or cherry-pick the new commit into `main`:

```
          A  [bug-fix]
         /
o---o---o  [old-release]
         \
          o---o---A'  [main]
```

If you don't have an `old-release` branch you can use the Git hash instead of a branch name when creating the `bug-fix` branch, e.g. with `git checkout -b bug-fix abcd1234`.